# Android OnHoverListener: app crashes when moving mouse inside view area

Tags: android, crash, hover, mouse

***EDIT:***

**I initialized canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,300, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); `drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);` app does not crash but also does not draw anything.. i test it with canvas.drawcolor(Color.RED) inside the HOVER MOVE case. Now,learning from the crash I KNOW it is recognizing my hover movement.. so why nothing happens now? any idea?**

I have an android 5.1 development board with a usb mouse connected. I need to perform some drawing operation when mouse is moved inside view window.
I am aware that the android studio emulator does not work with hover so all of my testing is on the development board itself

I added a hover listener to my     `OnCreate` method. I basically have a transparent view sitting on top of the camera2 video     `(textureview)`. Trying to listen to it.
As soon as I move the mouse inside app, it crashes. so it IS detecting the hover. need some help with the reason for the crash. here are all relevant code: Activit containing the Oncreate, my CustomView, and my XML

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }


        View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        container.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:

                        drawCanvas.drawCircle(50,50,100,canvasPaint);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:

                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }



}
```

customview:

```
public class CustomView extends View{

    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xff00ff00;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    //constructor
    public CustomView(Context context){
        super(context);
        setupDrawing();
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    //prepare drawing
    private void setupDrawing(){
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    //view assigned size
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    //draw view
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //respond to touch interaction
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // this code will be executed after 2 seconds
                        drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                    }
                }, 2000);

                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.example.android.camera2basic.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/texture2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/control_background">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/picture" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post error trace

Comment: Since the only way to check it is generating APK and running the app on the board, I dont have (dont know how to get them?)  any error logs.

Comment: You cant run the app into your board from android studio ?

Comment: nope, its a stand alone unit running android connected to a dedicated monitor. all my development is done on my PC. As a first step I figured maybe somthing is wrong with how I implemented the code, and how I set up the view to listen to.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can find something.

Comment: Maybe because the `drawCanvas` variable is not initialized ín the Activity.

Comment: initialized   `canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,300, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);`
      `  drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);`  app does not crash but also does not draw anything.. `i test it with canvas.drawcolor(Color.RED)` inside the HOVER MOVE case. Now,learning from the crash I KNOW it is recognizing my hover movement.. so why nothing happens now? any idea?